# Find the pattern in the months

Tags: mathematics, pattern

$\text{April} \times \text{May} - \text{June} = \text{December} - \text{January}$

$\text{September} \div \text{November} \times \text{December} = \text{March} \times \text{March}$

$\text{January} \times \text{February} \div (\text{February} + x ) = \text{April}$

---

These three equations follow a certain pattern. What month of the year fits in the spot marked $x$? Please provide a logical explanation as well.

Comment: Are the mathematical operators as one would expect? i.e. Is '*' ordinary multiplication and '/' division as we commonly think of it?

Comment: Yes, they are exactly what you use in maths. :)

Comment: @LUNA was this found in an IQ-test or did you make it up?

Comment: Oh, I've come up with it myself. Looks like I put in the "iq-test" tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is

> **August**

The math works as follows:

> On the left side of the equation, the months represent the count of letters in their names (**January** = 7, **February** = 8, etc.).
>
>  On the right side of the equation, the months represent their location in the calendar (**January** = 1, **February** = 2, etc.).

To solve for the missing month, we have:

> $ 7 \times 8 \div (8 + x) = 4$
>  $ 56 \div (8 + x) = 4$
>  $ 56 = 4(8 + x)$
>  $ 56 \div 4 = 8 + x$
>  $ 14 = 8 + x$
>  $ 14 - 8 = x$
>  $ x = 6$

The only month with

> $6$ letters in its name is **August**, so that is the solution.

Comment: Ah, Ninja'd. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

My guess:

> August.

Reasoning:

> The first two equations work if you replace months with the number of letters in their names on the left side of '=' and with their order in the year on the right side:
>
>  5 * 3 - 4 = 11 = 12 - 1
>  9 / 8 * 8 = 9 = 3 * 3
>  7 * 8 / (8 + _) = 4
>
>  6 is the number that fits in the gap, and August has six letters in its name.